# What is wrong with this Karatsuba Multiplication Algorithm Implementation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, karatsuba

First things first:

~ This is my first question on StackOverflow.

~ I am a university student.

~ This is not my homework problem (I am doing this to increase my algorithmic thinking).

Here is my implementation, which keeps on returning wrong answers. I've tried running **GDB**, but was too inexperienced to make out where the algorithm was going wrong. Please help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int equalize(string &num1, string &num2){  
    int len1 = num1.length();
    int len2 = num2.length();
    if (len1 < len2){
        for (int i = 0; i < len2 - len1; i++){
            num1 = '0' + num1;
        }
        return len2;
    } else{
        for (int i = 0; i < len1 - len2; i++){
            num2 = '0' + num2;
        }
        return len1;
    }
}

string add(string num1, string num2){
    string result;
    int length = equalize(num1, num2);
    int carryover = 0;
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        int a = num1[i] - '0';
        int b = num2[i] - '0';
        int sum = a + b + carryover;
        carryover = sum / 10;
        sum = sum % 10;
        result = to_string(sum) + result;
    }
    if (carryover)
        result = to_string(carryover) + result;
    return result;
}

long karatsuba(string num1, string num2){
    int n = equalize(num1, num2);
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1){
        return (num1[0] - '0') * (num2[0] - '0');
    } else{
        int primary = n / 2;
        int secondary = n - primary;
        string A = num1.substr(0, primary);
        string B = num1.substr(primary, secondary);
        string C = num2.substr(0, primary);
        string D = num2.substr(primary, secondary);
        long AC = karatsuba(A, C);
        long BD = karatsuba(B, D);
        long ABCD = karatsuba(add(A, B), add(C, D));
        return ((AC * pow(10, 2 * primary)) + ((ABCD - AC - BD) * pow(10, primary)) + (BD));
    }
}

int main() {
    string a = "111", b = "111";
    cout << karatsuba(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The answer returned is `441` which should ideally be `12321`.

Comment: What do you really want? return 1221 could solve youre problem now ;-). Please give more information..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour].  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  
Apart from "use gdb" the text has many other good hints. Maybe you can exercise using a debugger first, based on explicitly simple programs you understand anyway. That is another useful skill next to algorhitmic thinking.

Comment: Use the debugger by putting breakpoints all over your program. Normally you can see the value of your variables at particular moments and then guess where it goes wild.

Comment: You're right I see it now (after I had my cup of tea) still look here for comparison [Fast bignum square computation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214) you can use both mine and yours ... step in both with the same input and compare subresults where it goes wrong...

Comment: Btw why your karatsuba returns `long` when your inputs are `string`s? if you return string then you will not be bounded by long bit-width.

Comment: I know, I'll probably fix that too. For now I'm just focusing on making this work.

Comment: Don't worry, it is good question.

Comment: The length of the *less* significant parts needs to be the one used in scaling intermediate results.