# How to implement modular exponentiation?

Tags: python, algorithm, pow, modular-arithmetic, cryptanalysis

I am trying to calculate something like this: a^b mod c, where all three numbers are large.

Things I've tried:

1. Python's pow() function is taking hours and has yet to produce a result. (if someone could tell me how it's implemented that would be very helpful!)
2. A right-to-left binary method that I implemented, with O(log e) time, would take about 30~40 hours (don't wanna wait that long).
3. Various recursion methods are producing segmentation faults (after I changed the recursion limits)

Any optimizations I could make?

Comment: see [Fast bignum square computation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214) With such big numbers I would try NTT based Schönhage-Strassen multiplication instead of karatsuba ... also power by squaring usualy involves sqr for which is NTT based sqr even faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses Karatsuba multiplication so the running time of multiplication is O(n^1.585). But division is still O(n^2).

For exponentiation, Python uses a left-to-right method with a 5-bit window. (It consumes 5 bits at once instead of just 1 bit. It does use more memory but will generally be faster.)

To get faster computations, you may want to look at [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2). It wraps the GMP multiple-precision library and will be faster. I ran a quick test and I think it will be ~100x faster.

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2.

Comment: I actually used gmpy2 at first. I used gmpy2.powmod(mpz(a), mpz(b), mpz(c)). My computer freezes when it's used for some reason. Is there anything I could do to optimize that?

Comment: Not really. There is no checking for interrupts so the calculation can't be interrupted. BTW, gmpy2.powmod(a,b,c) is sufficient; the arguments are automatically converted to mpz. Is there anything special about any of the values?

Comment: As far as I know, they are just large numbers (~120000 digits). Specifically, I'm trying to implement a fast decryption of RSA. (a, b, c) here are the ciphertext, the private key, and the modulo, respectively.

Comment: @abforlife When RSA is used to encrypt in practice, a message of any length is encrypted with a symmetric algorithm (like AES) using a random key.  Then that key (only 256 bits long or so) is encrypted with RSA.

Comment: Picking a some numbers at random, the running time on my machine should be around 30 minutes. But what @MattTimmermans said...

Comment: @casevh This RSA (not used in practice) is designed to be weird I think. I think the desirable time should be around 30 minutes or less but not sure where I'm messing up though. (I'm using a Macbook Pro)

Comment: I'm using on a Skylake CPU @3.7 GHz and I think 30 minutes is possible on that class of CPU. Not sure about a Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to evaluate `pow(a, b) % c`. You should be using the 3-argument form, `pow(a, b, c)`, which takes advantage of the fact that `a * b mod c == a mod c * b mod c`, which means you can reduce subproducts as they are computed while computing `a ^ b`, rather than having to do all the multiplications first.

Comment: Yes, I'm using pow(a, b, c). The naive implementation would take O(e) time.