# "How can I optimize a recursive algorithm for calculating Fibonacci numbers in C++?"

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, recursion, fibonacci

I'm working on a project that involves calculating Fibonacci numbers in C++ using a recursive algorithm. My current implementation follows the traditional recursive approach, but it exhibits performance issues for larger Fibonacci numbers. Here's what I've done so far:

```
#include <iostream>

int fibonacci(int n) {    
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    }
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

int main() {
    int n = 10; // Example: Calculate Fibonacci(10)
    std::cout << "Fibonacci(" << n << ") = " << fibonacci(n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've noticed that for Fibonacci numbers beyond a certain value, the algorithm becomes slow and consumes a lot of memory.I've been exploring ways to optimize this algorithm, but I'm not sure where to start. Are there any techniques or strategies I can use to make it faster and more memory-efficient? I'd appreciate any guidance or code examples that can help me improve the performance of my Fibonacci calculator.

Comment: There are other problems: On larger values you risk a *stack overflow*. And signed integer overflow.

Comment: First step: Don't use recursion. Use an iterative approach instead. Why do you want to optimize a recursive algorithm?

Comment: Use iteration instead of recursion, and only keep track of the last 2 elements (and update them after each iteration).

Comment: Any recursive algorithm can be converted to an iterative one. Which would reduce to just allocating a std::vector with {1,1} and then filling out the blanks... Fun fact you can even do this at compile time.

Comment: 1. agree with jabaa iteration is the way. 2. you can use fast approach by using [power by squaring on matrix approach to compute fibonacci](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms) which will improve speed a lot for bigger inputs  3.  memoization can help too if you query a lot of fibonacci numbers and have memory to spare ... for #2 do not forget to use [faster multiplication algorithms like Karatsuba or better](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214) if you are on huge numbers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use memoization so you don't have to recalculate the same Fibonacci numbers many times. I.e., maintain a map of n->fib(n), and check it before calculating a Fibonacci numbers. If n isn't a key, go ahead and calculate, otherwise return the associated value.

Answer (score 2):

This code will have (almost) no runtime cost.
All numbers (up to 30th) will be calculated at compile time without recursion

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

template<std::size_t N>
static auto constexpr initialize_fibonacci_numbers()
{
    static_assert(N >= 2);
    std::array<std::uint64_t, N> values{0,1};
    for (std::size_t n = 2; n < N; ++n)
    {
        values[n] = values[n - 1] + values[n - 2];
    }
    return values;
}

int main()
{
    static constexpr auto fibonacci_number = initialize_fibonacci_numbers<30>();
    return fibonacci_number[12];
}
```

Compiles to : https://godbolt.org/z/EeEsvnjWs

```
main:                                   # @main
        mov     eax, 144
        ret
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this version for example:

```
int Fibonacci(int n) 
{
    int count =0, n0=0,n1=1,tmp;
    while (++count <= n) 
    {
        tmp = n1;
        n1 += n0;
        n0 = tmp;
        
    }
    return n0;
}
```

Notice that:

- no recursion
- each value is calculated only once.